# how to make an array of logo running in reactjs and tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i have seen many implementation of this but somehow i don't know what to search, and i can only get the html and css in inspect, maybe there are some people that have the same problem with me.

usually we want to implement this to show the past clients or portfolio.

the one that i have is working but it always stutter every time it trying to loop the array of image, this is my react components

```
const clients = [
    {
        name: 'google',
        logo: Google,
    },
    {
        name: 'asus',
        logo: Asus
    },
    {
        name: 'byu',
        logo: Byu,
    },
    {
        name: 'kominfo',
        logo: Kominfo
    },
    {
        name: 'Telkom',
        logo: Telkom,
    },
    {
        name: 'Bank Indonesia',
        logo: Bi,
    },
    // Add more clients as needed
];

 <div className='overflow-hidden py-8'>
                    <div className='flex animate-left'>
                        <div className=" flex w-max  gap-8 mr-4">
                            {clients.map((client, index) => (
                                <a key={index} href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center shadow-md rounded-xl p-6 w-[10rem] ">
                                    <Image src={client.logo} alt={client.name} width={100} height={100} className="w-full h-full object-contain" />
                                </a>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        <div className=" flex w-max   gap-8  ">
                            {clients.map((client, index) => (
                                <a key={index} href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center shadow-md rounded-xl p-6 w-[10rem] ">
                                    <Image src={client.logo} alt={client.name} width={100} height={100} className="w-full h-full object-contain" />
                                </a>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and my tailwind config :

```
    extend: {
      animation: {
        'left': 'bannermoveleft 20s linear infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        bannermoveleft: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(-50%)' },
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `width: max-content` to the scrolling element via `w-max`, so that the `-50%` in the `transform` in `bannermoveleft` corresponds to a "width" of one of the clones of items.

Apply `gap: theme(spacing.8)` via `gap-8` on the scrolling element and remove the `mr-4` on the first clone group so that the gaps between the clones is the same as the gaps between each item.

Subtract half of the `gap` in the `translateX()` of `bannermoveleft` so that we  seamlessly `translateX()` until the second clone group's left edge matches the start of the animation. This makes the loop seamless:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        'left': 'bannermoveleft 5s linear infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        bannermoveleft: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(calc(-50% - (theme(spacing.8) / 2)))' },
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

const Google = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100';
const Asus = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100?';
const Byu = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100?0';
const Kominfo = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100?1';
const Telkom = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100?2';
const Bi = 'https://picsum.photos/100/100?3';

const clients = [
    {
        name: 'google',
        logo: Google,
    },
    {
        name: 'asus',
        logo: Asus
    },
    {
        name: 'byu',
        logo: Byu,
    },
    {
        name: 'kominfo',
        logo: Kominfo
    },
    {
        name: 'Telkom',
        logo: Telkom,
    },
    {
        name: 'Bank Indonesia',
        logo: Bi,
    },
    // Add more clients as needed
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='overflow-hidden py-8'>
      <div className='flex animate-left gap-8 w-max'>
        <div className=" flex w-max gap-8">
          {clients.map((client, index) => (
            <a key={index} href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center shadow-md rounded-xl p-6 w-[10rem] ">
              <img src={client.logo} alt={client.name} width={100} height={100} className="w-full h-full object-contain" />
            </a>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className=" flex w-max gap-8">
          {clients.map((client, index) => (
            <a key={index} href="#" className="flex justify-center items-center shadow-md rounded-xl p-6 w-[10rem] ">
              <img src={client.logo} alt={client.name} width={100} height={100} className="w-full h-full object-contain" />
            </a>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```